# Adding a responsive button or anchor to update an index in a database table

Tags: php

I am trying to add a button or an anchor to update on the 'status' column either "Approved" or "Declined".

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `section`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

echo "<table border='1'>"; 
echo "<tr><th>" . "Request #" . "</th> <th>" . "Student Name" . "</th> <th>" . "Student #" . "</th> <th>" . "Course Name " . "</th> <th>" . "Course #" . "</th> </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['request'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['studentName'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['studentNumber'] . "</td><td>" . $row['courseName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['courseNumber'] . "</td><td>" . "<a href='???'></a>" . "</td></tr>";
```

I want the admin to either approve or decline, I know i may need an extra column (one for approving, one for declining) 
And can this be done with a drop down list ?

Answer (score -1):

1. Home.php

   ```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       if ($row['studentName'] == $_POST['']) {
           echo "<tr><td>" . $row['request'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['studentName'] 
               ."</td> <td>" . $row['studentNumber'] . "</td><td>" . $row['courseName'] 
               ."</td><td>" . $row['courseNumber'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['status'] 
               ."</td><td>" . "<a href='app.php?id=".$row['request']."'>Approve</a>" . "</td><td>" . "<a href='dec.php?id=".$row['request']."'>Decline</a>" . "</td></tr>";
       }
   }

   echo "</table>";

   mysqli_close($conn);
   ```
2. app.php (approve request)

```
    include('approve.php');
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $db = "university";
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // echo "<br>";
    // echo ($id);

    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "UPDATE `section` SET `status`='Approved' WHERE `request` = $id"; 

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location: home.php'); 
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Error Updating record";
    }
?>
```

3. dec.php (decline request)

```
    include('approve.php');
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $db = "university";
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "UPDATE `section` SET `status`='Declined' WHERE `request` = $id"; 

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location: approve.php'); 
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Error Updating record";
    }
?>
```

Comment: WARNING: When using mysqli you should be using parameterized queries and bind_param to add any data to your query. DO NOT use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe SQL injection bug. NEVER put $_POST, $_GET or data of any kind directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.